# Update href query param using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have URL with some query params as indicated below. I need to replace the value of the query parameters using the view model (Knockout).

```
<http://localhost:85/Default.aspx?FormName=Default&ControlNameAndValue={Control1,Control_Value},{Control2,Control2_Value}#/Default.aspx>
```

In the abovelink I need to replace "Control1_Value" with the "param1" and "Control2_Value" with "param2" from the below ViewModel properties,

```
var FormDetailsViewModel{
param1: ko.Observable("XYZ"),
param2: ko.Observable("ABC")
}
```

I tried below URL but didn't work, I got error as improper binding.

```
"<http://localhost:85/Default.aspx?FormName=Default&ControlNameAndValue={Control1," + FormDetailsViewModel.param1() + "},{Control2," + FormDetailsViewModel.param2() + "}#/Default.aspx>"
```

Not sure what wrong I am doing in the above href or is there some other way to achieve this using knockout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest having an observable in your viewmodel which returns the full, constructed URL through a [`ko.computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

```
var FormDetailsViewModel = {
  param1: ko.observable("foo"),
  param2: ko.observable("bar"),
  url: ko.computed(function() {
    return "http://localhost:85/Default.aspx?FormName=Default&ControlNameAndValue={Control1," + this.param1() + "},{Control2," + this.param2() + "}#/Default.aspx";
  })
}
```

and using the `attr` binding to set the href:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: url }">My link</a>
```